# Check if user input matches array of values. PHP

Tags: php, validation, forms, redirect

I have one field (for zip code), if user enters zip code that matches one in my array and click "go" - they are redirected to the next step, if not - display "out of our service area" message. Form and php script are on the same page. How Do I do redirection inside  That's what I have so far.

```
     <form>
<input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
<?php 
$allowedzips = array("10051", "10061", "10071", "10081");
$input = echo $_POST["zipcode"];
$input = str_split($input);
$message = "Out of our service area";
foreach($input as $zip) {
    if (in_array($zip, $allowedzips)) {
        $message //redirect goes here
        break;
    }
}
echo $message;

?>
```

Comment: what is this line: `$input = echo $_POST["zipcode"];` that is **not** valid php

Comment: trying to get zipcode input value. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 1):

A PHP redirect is quite easy to do:

```
header('Location: www.example.com');
exit;
```

Make sure to `exit;`, as that will stop the script from executing any further.

Comment: A quick note on using header. It needs to be above anything that would display something on the page or it won't work. So you might need to have your PHP code in a different file that gets called on submit so you can place the header('Location: www......com') before things are displayed.

Comment: I don't think so. The page keeps "loading" as long as the script executes, and since `header()` is part of the execution process, it'll execute. Try it on a server with PHP.

Comment: @bmbaeb is right, if you echo any html prior to the header() function call, it will cause the header to fail

Comment: Okay, that sounds familiar. I haven't coded PHP for websites in a while (Python's my thing), so I'm a bit rusty with mu PHP...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use javascript instead of PHP for how you are looking to do this.

What I would do is add this into the head of your html

```
<script type="test/javascript">

    function checkZipCode(zip) {
        var myZipCodes=new Array("10051", "10061", "10071", "10081");
        for(i=0;i<myZipCodes.length;i++) {
            if (zip = myZipCodes[i]) {
                form.submit;
            }
            else
                window.location = "redirectpage";
        }
    }

</script>
```

And then on submit call and pass the zip code to checkZipCode.

Comment: Don't forget to re-validate the zip on the server side upon form submission. I can easily modify your javascript on my client to allow me to send any zip.

Comment: I agree with @horatio, in the php script that goes over the form after it is submitted you should also validate before the data gets processed.

Comment: doesn't work for me... all it does is adds  ?zipcode=10051   at the end

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in PHP to ensure that you're not tricked on the client side

Use the `in_array()` function to determine if the element you're looking for is within you list of valid zip codes, and redirect accordingly.